# E-R diagram task - feedback wanted

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Doing practise exam questions. Was just looking for some feedback on my attempt at this task. Do you think this caters for what it's asking for, is it missing anything?

[image]

[image]

Comment: oops just noticed I forgot to annotate the relationships!